# How can I convince AWS CLI sync to exclude any file matching a directory pattern?

Tags: amazon-s3, wildcard, aws-cli

The use case is I want to exclude certain data from going up to S3. The files could be anywhere within the file hierarchy, but if they are contained anywhere below a directory named `foobar` I don't want them copied over.

For example:

```
/my-data/20150806-1600/foobar/blah.csv  # Exclude
/my-data/20150806-1600/dingbat/blah.csv # Include
/my-data/clients/foobar/README.txt      # Exclude

$ /usr/local/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.117 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-92-generic botocore/1.5.80
```

Alas ...

```
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync /my-data/ s3://my-bucket/my-data/ --exclude '*/foobar/*' --exclude '*/foobaz/*' --delete
```

The files still upload. I have tried changing the exclude pattern(s) to `foobar/*` and `*foobar*` but in every case, files matching a parent directory with `foobar` in the path still get uploaded.

Comment: `--exclude '*foobar/*'` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it only seemed to work by excluding `*foobar*` or `*foorbar/*`. It would *not* work by excluding `*/foobar/*`:

```
$ ls -lR stack
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  wheel  102  8 Jul 23:25 foobar
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel    5  8 Jul 23:25 level1

stack/foobar:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel  5  8 Jul 23:25 level2

$ aws s3 sync stack/ s3://my-bucket --exclude '*foobar*'
upload: stack/level1 to s3://my-bucket/level1
```